# If $f_X(x) = x/8$, find the pdf of $Z = \log (x/4)$.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, transformation

> Given the function $f_{X}(x)  = \left\{
>   \begin{array}{lr}
>     \ \frac{x}{8} \quad & : 0 <x <4 \\
>     0 &  :\text{Otherwise}
>   \end{array}
> \right.
> $
>   Find the PDF of $Z = \log_{e}(\frac{x}{4})$

By using method of transformations I got my equation to be $f_{Z}(z)  = \left\{
  \begin{array}{lr}
    \ 2e^{2z} \\
    0 &  :\text{Otherwise}
  \end{array}
\right.
$

But I get my limits for $2e^{2z}$ as $-{\infty} < z < 0$ which I don't think looks right. Just wondering how I find my limits for this method?

Comment: Why $-\infty < z < 0$ doesn't look right?

Comment: thats what im asking, not sure how to get these values i thought you would sub 0 and 4 in to the Z equation, but log(0) gives a math error.

Comment: $\ln x \to -\infty$ when $x\to 0$.

Answer (score 1):

The cdf of $X$ is
$$F_X(x)=\begin{cases}
0, &\text{if }& -\infty<x<0,\\
\int_0^x \frac y8 dy=\frac 1{16}x^2,&\text{if }&0\le x\le4,\\
1,&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

With this, the cdf of $Z$:

$$F_Z(x)=P\left(\ln \left(\frac X4\right)<x\right)=P\left(X<4e^x\right)=F_X(4e^x)=$$
$$=\begin{cases}e^{2x}, \text{ if } &-\infty<x\le0\\
1, &\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

**because $4e^x$ is between $0$ and $4$ if $-\infty<x\le 0$.**

So, the pdf of $Z$,
$$f_Z(x)=\frac{dF_Z(x)}{dx}=\begin{cases}2e^{2x},\text{ if } &-\infty<x\le0\\
0,& \text{otherwise.}\end{cases}
$$